# How to separate arrays (type structs) in Go?

Tags: string, go, types

I just created this code to experiment with `type`, i will explain the problems later.

My Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

type Games struct {
    game    string
    creator string
}

func main() {
    videogames := []Games{
        {"inFamous", "Sucker Punch Games"},
        {"Halo", "343 Games"},
        {"JustCause", "Eidos"},
    }
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    i := rand.Intn(len(videogames))
    fmt.Print(videogames[i])
}
```

If I run this the result will be,

```
{inFamous,Sucker Punch Games}
```

Now what i want to do is separate the arrays so that the result will be,

```
Game = inFamous
Publisher = Sucker Punch Games
```

Also i need to remove the opening and closing brackets.

Answer (score 3):

You need a stringer method to define how your object will be printed:

```
func (g Games) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Game = %v, Creator = %v", g.game, g.creator)
}
```

Check out the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/17)

Answer (score 1):

`fmt.Print()` does not allow you to specify the format, but will use the type default format.

Instead, use `fmt.Printf()`. This should do what you need:

```
fmt.Printf("Game = %s\nPublisher = %s", videogames[i].game, videogames[i].creator)
```